# Remove pictures in defined area

Tags: excel, vba

I insert an image into the specified area (rngOblastVlozeni). But before inserting the image, I want to remove all the images that have been there so far.

I use the following part of VBA to do this:

```
Dim shpObjekt As Shape 

With rngOblastVlozeni.Parent 

    For Each shpObjekt In .Shapes           

        If Application.Intersect(shpObjekt.TopLeftCell, rngOblastVlozeni) Is Nothing Then   

        Else 

            If (shpObjekt.Type = msoPicture) Or (shpObjekt.Type = msoLinkedPicture) Then    

                shpObjekt.Delete                                                                

            End If 

        End If 

    Next shpObjekt 

End With
```

But in some cases I receive error

```
Run-time error '1004':

Application-defined or object-defined error
```

The error is in the line `If Application.Intersect(shpObjekt.TopLeftCell, rngOblastVlozeni) Is Nothing Then` , probably in part `shpObjekt.TopLeftCell`.

When I tried to capture it in more detail:

- I have two pictures and one graph on the sheet
- I insert another image in the designated area

If the area is EMPTY, then two shpObjects will pass without error, and the error will not appear until the third one.

If there IS an image in the area, then three shpObjects are OK, and the error is on the fourth.

When I remove both images and the graph, as well as any image in the area, the error still appears (if there is no image, then as the first shpObject if there is an image, then as the second shpObject) - from this I deduce that the error is not with any of these images .

Could there be more to the Shapes collection? For example, from a previous event?

And if so, can someone advise on adding the code so that I "ignore" the error ONLY in the case of this error and ONLY in this part of VBA, and jump to the Next shpObjekt when it occurs?

One more addition - if I use the absolutely same code on another sheet, it doesn't seem to cause this problem, i.e. it happens without any problems - i.e. it seems that I have some extra object on the problematic sheet, which I am not able to find. I tried F5 - Go to all objects, I deleted them, but the problem was not solved - i.e. it is probably not a visible object?

So, question:

1. is it possible there is another `Shape Object` on my sheet? Is it possible to identify it somehow?
2. any reccommendation how to skip part

   ```
   If Application.Intersect(shpObjekt.TopLeftCell, rngOblastVlozeni) Is Nothing Then  

     Else 

       If (shpObjekt.Type = msoPicture) Or (shpObjekt.Type = msoLinkedPicture) Then    

           shpObjekt.Delete                                                                

      End If : End If
   ```

in case  `If Application.Intersect(shpObjekt.TopLeftCell, rngOblastVlozeni) Is Nothing` generates error 1004 (optimally ONLY this error)?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your specific two questions:

1. I can't say whether there is another Shape in your sheet without having the sheet here in front of me, but you can use `Debug.Print` to test (see code below)
2. Test if shpObjekt and its Address property are not Nothing (again, see code below)

```
Dim shpObjekt As Shape

With rngOblastVlozeni.Parent

    For Each shpObjekt In .Shapes

        If Not shpObjekt Is Nothing Then
            
            If Not shpObjekt.TopLeftCell Is Nothing Then
                
                If Application.Intersect(shpObjekt.TopLeftCell, rngOblastVlozeni) Is Nothing Then
                
                    Debug.Print "Not intersecting:", shpObjekt.Name, shpObjekt.TopLeftCell.Address, shpObjekt.Type
                
                Else
                    
                    Debug.Print "Intersecting:", shpObjekt.Name, shpObjekt.TopLeftCell.Address, shpObjekt.Type
                    
                    If (shpObjekt.Type = msoPicture) Or (shpObjekt.Type = msoLinkedPicture) Then
    
                        shpObjekt.Delete
    
                    End If
    
                End If
            
            End If
        
        End If

    Next shpObjekt

End With
```

In addition, I think the root cause of the problem you are having is quite likely you are using a For Each to iterate over a Collection (ie of Shapes) while deleting members of that Collection ... it is better to use For Next and loop backwards when deleting ... for this, your code would become

```
Dim shpObjekt As Shape

Dim index As Long

With rngOblastVlozeni.Parent

    For index = .Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1

        Set shpObjekt = .Shapes.Item(index)
        
        If Not shpObjekt Is Nothing Then

            If Not shpObjekt.TopLeftCell Is Nothing Then

                If Application.Intersect(shpObjekt.TopLeftCell, rngOblastVlozeni) Is Nothing Then

                    Debug.Print "Not intersecting:", shpObjekt.Name, shpObjekt.TopLeftCell.Address, shpObjekt.Type

                Else

                    Debug.Print "Intersecting:", shpObjekt.Name, shpObjekt.TopLeftCell.Address, shpObjekt.Type

                    If (shpObjekt.Type = msoPicture) Or (shpObjekt.Type = msoLinkedPicture) Then

                        shpObjekt.Delete

                    End If

                End If

            End If

        End If

    Next index

End With
```

Comment: Hi, I used `MsgBox` to get more information about strange object - I identified name - "Drop Down 154" and type = 8 (Form control). But this object do not have assigned any address. But because I check first the adress and then the type, it cannot work.

Comment: Quick solution for me is first to check the type, and second to check the address (only for pictures). Alternative solution is to remove the object itself - I expect I do not need it.

Comment: So solution is based on fact, that object type Form control does not have it address assigned.